# CakePHP: Session->write() not working

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-cookies

I'm building a very basic auth system for specific pages which require a password to view. I've found several other questions that sound similar, but the only ones with clear solutions involve config settings that don't seem to resolve my problem. For some reason `$this->Session->write(...)` always returns false.

Here's my config setting:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));
```

Here's where I try to write the session in the controller action:

```
private function _handle_auth_attempt( $object ) {
    $submitted_pass = $this->request->data['Object']['password'];
    $correct_pass = $object['Object']['password'];
    $auth_cookie_name = $this->Object->auth_cookie_name($object);

    debug($auth_cookie_name); //'Object1.pass'
    debug($submitted_pass); //'foobar'

    if ( md5($submitted_pass) == md5($correct_pass) ) {
        $write1 = $this->Session->write( $auth_cookie_name, md5($submitted_pass) );
        $write2 = CakeSession::write( $auth_cookie_name, md5($submitted_pass) );            
        debug($write1); //FALSE
        debug($write2); //FALSE
        return TRUE;
    }

    $this->Session->setFlash('The password you entered is incorrect.');
    $this->redirect( $this->referer() );

}
```

**Update**

Inside `_handle_auth_attempt()` I added:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
$this->Session-read('foo'); //'bar'
```

...and they work fine. So I'm pretty sure this isn't a permissions problem.

Comment: Are you adding SessionComponent to the controller?

Comment: have u cleared browser cache?

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla I debugged $component and I see Session, Cookie and Auth in the array right before the ->write(...).

Comment: @praveen I switched browsers and the situation is the same.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code, one possibilities of FALSE is that the session name is empty.
So can you check what result is

```
debug($auth_cookie_name);
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I have debugged all the variables and they're as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this at all, but I removed the "." from inside my session cookie's name and it causes `Session->write()` to work again.

```
$this->Session->write('Object1.pass'); //FALSE
$this->Session->write('Object1pass'); //TRUE
```

Although this solves my immediate problem, I'd love to understand this problem better.

**Update**

After thinking this through more, I suspect that what was happening is a combination of factors:

1. CakePHP uses the "dot" notation to store session inside arrays which I wasn't accounting for.
2. The very first time I ran the code, it probably worked...
3. But every subsequent attempt it returned `FALSE` because it already existed <--untested
4. I have no explanation why `read()` was returning false.

Answer (score 0):

All your session read/writes belong in the controller:

```
$this->Session->write('User.still_login', 'Yes');

echo $this->Session->read('User.still_login'); // Yes as output
```